# Is it possible - border layout location from values form array?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout

I have 5 labels in grid layout frame. I would like to change gridlayout to border layout with using  names of location from an array (e.g. String gborders[] = { "North", "Center", "South", "East", "West" }; ) and enumerate label location. Is it possible?

That is what I have:

```
package w1;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LayShow {

  private static JLabel lLabel;

  public static void main(String[] args) {


    int t = 15;

    String lmNames[] = {"Label 1", "Label 2", 
            "Label 3", "Label 4", "Label 5"};


    String gborders[] = { "North", "Center", "South", "East", "West" };

    Color colors[] = { new Color(11, 125, 155), new Color(155, 55, 200),
        new Color(201, 245, 145), new Color(255, 255, 140),
        new Color(161, 224, 224), new Color(11, 125, 155) };


    Font fonts[] = {new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, t), 
            new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, t+1), 
            new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, t+2), 
            new Font("SansSerif", Font.ITALIC, t+3),
            new Font("SansSerif", Font.ITALIC, t+4)};


    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame"); 
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));


    for (int i = 0; i < lmNames.length; i++) {


      final Border
      borderColor = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(colors[i+1]);    
      JPanel p = new JPanel();
      p.setBackground(colors[i]);  
      p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(borderColor , lmNames[i])); 

      lLabel = new JLabel("label number: " + (i+1));
      p.add(lLabel);
      lLabel.setFont(fonts[i]);
      lLabel.setForeground(colors[i+1]);
      lLabel.setToolTipText("ToolTip for label number: " + (i+1));

      frame.add(p);
    }
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: So what problem are you having?

Comment: You should not declare lLabel as a static variable but rather as a local variable of your method. You should try to avoid non-final static variables as much as you can. They are the root of all evil and often lead to memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following

```
String[] gborders =  { BorderLayout.NORTH,BorderLayout.CENTER, 
                      BorderLayout.SOUTH, BorderLayout.WEST, BorderLayout.EAST };
```

Add all inner panels in a single panel

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame"); 
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
panel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

at the end of for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < lmNames.length; i++) {
  ....
  lLabel.setToolTipText("ToolTip for label number: " + (i+1));
  panel1.add(p,gborders[i]);
}
frame.add(panel1);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Done.